# batch outputting with space after each string

Tags: batch-file

Hey i currently have this code to turn different text from different text files into variables then output into one file:

```
@echo off
echo system starting..
cls
echo grabbing versions 
cd C:\Scripts\Bamboo
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%n IN (CurrentBuild.txt) DO SET build-version-number=%%n
cd C:\Users\Administrator\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\MC-CC-MAIN
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%n IN (MinecraftVersion.txt) DO SET minecraft-version-number=%%n
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%n IN (ForgeVersion.txt) DO SET forge-version-number=%%n
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%n IN (ModVersion.txt) DO SET mod-version-number=%%n
cls
echo setting versions to variables
set mod-version=mod_version = %mod-version-number%
set forge-version=forge_version = %forge-version-number%
set build-version=build_version = %build-version-number%
set minecraft-version=minecraft_version = %minecraft-version-number%
cls
echo outputing variables to build.properties
del build.properties
@echo %minecraft-version% >> build.properties
@echo %forge-version% >> build.properties
@echo %mod-version% >> build.properties
@echo %build-version% >> build.properties
cls
echo done, exiting inject script 
exit
```

but the output has spaces (whitline) after each one:

```
"minecraft_version = 1.7.10 "
"forge_version = 10.13.2.1291 "
"mod_version = v1.0 "
"build_version = 33 "
```

no sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the space preceding the `>` or `>>` redirector. Remove it as follows (**edited** in regard of [dbenham's benefitting comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/47108034?noredirect=1)):

```
(@echo %minecraft-version%)>> build.properties
```

or

```
>> build.properties (@echo %minecraft-version%)
```

Explanation:

- `@echo %minecraft-version%>> build.properties` could break output if the variable `%minecraft-version%` *ends* with a single digit preceded with a space;
- `>> build.properties @echo %minecraft-version%` does not suffice as the line could contain an unwanted (forgotten) trailing space.

Moreover, to keep full control on leading and trailing spaces in variable names and values, use double quotes in `set` command as follows:

```
set "variable=value"
```

Think out others:

```
set "variable= this value contains a leading space"
set "variable= this value surrounded with spaces "
set "variable=this value contains a trailing space "
set "variable =this variable name contains a trailing space"
```

Applied to some commands in your  script:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%n IN (ModVersion.txt) DO SET "mod-version-number=%%n"
:::
set "mod-version=mod_version = %mod-version-number%"
```

etc.

Comment: @user3327050 please "accept" this answer as a measure of your gratitude. That's how StackOverflow works!

Comment: @Stephan yes, but your statement applies to the first occurrence of `=` only in `set "variable=value"`. And `value` contains ` = ` surrounded by spaces by design here!

Comment: @Stefan please do not remove comments (those with a reply to) as doing that the discussion becomes a bit unclear for other readers... <EOT>

Comment: Note - this will not work if a version is ever a single digit. For example, `echo some_version = 1>> build.properties` would treat the 1 as the file handle to be redirected, The simplest solution is to put the redirection before the command like so: `>>build.properties echo some_version = 1`

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the space in the batch file. This test file

```
@echo three >testbat.txt
```

generates a text file containing the line `"three "` with a trailing space. But this one

```
@echo three>testbat.txt
```

generates a text file containing the line `"three"` without a trailing space.

Comment: Too late but posted anyway.