# How to write to different lines of a text file with batch

Tags: batch-file, text

I wrote the following code:

```
@echo off
title Kiel Configurations
rem Credits Will Go Here
rem Website Here
color 08
echo **********************************************************************
echo **************************Kiel Configuration**************************
echo **********************************************************************
echo ======================================================================
echo Use yes/no to configure the following options
pause
cls
echo Would you like it to run in fake mode? (recommended for slow computers or for the paranoid)
set /p FakeModeVar=(yes/no):
cls
echo Would you like to close skype?
set /p SkypeVar=(yes/no):
cls
echo Woud you like to close spotify?
set /p SpotifyVar=(yes/no):
cls
echo Would you like to close steam?
set /p SteamVar=(yes/no)
cls
echo Would you like to close chrome? (reccommended)
set /p ChromeVar=(yes/no):
cls
echo Which chrome profile would you like chrome to open as? (Ask me if unsure)
set /p ChromeProfile=(1,2,3...):
cls
echo Now configurating you settings...
pause >nul
if %FakeModeVar%==yes goto Locate1
if %FakeModeVar%==no goto Locate2
:Locate1
echo yes> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate3
:Locate2
echo no> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate3
:Locate3
if %SkypeVar%==yes goto Locate4
if %SkypeVar%==no goto Locate5
:Locate4
echo yes>> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate6
:Locate5
echo no>> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate6
:Locate6
if %SpotifyVar%==yes goto Locate7
if %SpotifyVar%==no goto Locate8
:Locate7
echo yes>>> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate9
:Locate 8
echo no>>> ConfigVarini.txt
goto locate9
:Locate9
if %SteamVar%==yes goto Locate10
if %Steamvar%==no goto Locate11
:Locate10
echo yes>>>> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate12
:Locate11
echo no>>>> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate12
:Locate12
if %ChromeVar%==yes goto Locate13
if %ChromeVar%==no goto Locate14
:Locate13
echo yes>> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate15
:Locate14
echo no>>>>> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate15
:Locate15
if %ChromeProfile%==1 goto Locate16
if %ChromeProfile%==2 goto Locate17
if %ChromeProfile%==3 goto Locate18
:Locate16
echo 1>>>>> ConfigVarini.txt
goto End
:Locate17
echo 2>>>>>> ConfigVarini.txt
goto End
:Locate18
echo 3>>>>>> ConfigVarini.txt
goto End
:End
cls
echo Files Configured!
```

When i run it i want it to take the user through a configuration process then save their preferences to a text file called `ConfigVarini.txt`
Then i will have another program that reads the settings on the text file. However the file on says

> yes yes

and it saves no other settings.

Comment: Writing to the file multiple times may not be the best idea and provides more chances for issues to happen. Try adding the values as you go along to a variable (string) that you will then write to the text file. Other than that you could try something like this: `echo "yes\n" > aTextFile.txt` This should write the value to the file with a line break.

Comment: Is this your actual code? `ECHO` statements with more than two redirect symbols, like `echo yes>>> ConfigVarini.txt` will not work. You will get `> was unexpected at this time.`.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can append to a batch file using ">>"

```
@echo off
echo Hi >> test.txt
echo Hello >> test.txt
echo. >>test.txt
echo 3 >> test.txt
```

Results in A file called test.txt containing

```
Hi
Hello

3
```

Im not sure what excatly you want besides this.
Also its good practice to leave a space before a inputting to a file since numbers from one to nine will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Imho  best practice: initially, empty your output file using

```
type nul> ConfigVarini.txt
```

and all further writing by either

```
(ECHO any text)>> ConfigVarini.txt
```

or

```
>> ConfigVarini.txt (ECHO any text)
```

Note:

- no  space preceding `>` nor `>>` [redirection operator](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) nor `)` closing parenthesis. Otherwise, that space appears as a trailing one in output file (could be at least weird or even harmful);
- `()` parentheses: important if output text *ends* with a *single digit* `0`, `1`, ..., `9` .

**Explication** (examples given with `1` but valid for any single decimal digit):

- `echo 1>> ConfigVarini.txt`  appends **nothing** (or an empty line or `ECHO is on/off` text) to output file as the CLI or batch parser treats a single decimal digit as the numeric file handle to be redirected (see *redirection* link above);
- `echo 1 >> ConfigVarini.txt` appends `1` with trailing space;
- `>> ConfigVarini.txt ECHO 1` appends `1` but we can't be sure whether there is an unwanted (forgotten) trailing space;
- `>> ConfigVarini.txt (ECHO 1)` appends `1` without trailing space;
- `(echo 1)>> ConfigVarini.txt` appends `1` without trailing space;

[More explanation and discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29450051/3439404)

Answer (score 0):

One single > will overwrite whatever might be in ConfigVarini.txt and add only ONE line. Two >> will add another line on a new line and leave the previously written content intact. With the code below each time Locate1 or Locate2 is started old settings will be overwritten and new ones applied. (I didn't properly check all the code, only changed your flawed >> usage. Someone check and edit if needed)

```
@echo off
title Kiel Configurations
rem Credits Will Go Here
rem Website Here
color 08
echo **********************************************************************
echo **************************Kiel Configuration**************************
echo **********************************************************************
echo ======================================================================
echo Use yes/no to configure the following options
pause
cls
echo Would you like it to run in fake mode? (recommended for slow computers or for the paranoid)
set /p FakeModeVar=(yes/no):
cls
echo Would you like to close skype?
set /p SkypeVar=(yes/no):
cls
echo Woud you like to close spotify?
set /p SpotifyVar=(yes/no):
cls
echo Would you like to close steam?
set /p SteamVar=(yes/no)
cls
echo Would you like to close chrome? (reccommended)
set /p ChromeVar=(yes/no):
cls
echo Which chrome profile would you like chrome to open as? (Ask me if unsure)
set /p ChromeProfile=(1,2,3...):
cls
echo Now configurating you settings...
pause >nul
if %FakeModeVar%==yes goto Locate1
if %FakeModeVar%==no goto Locate2
:Locate1
echo yes > ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate3
:Locate2
echo no > ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate3
:Locate3
if %SkypeVar%==yes goto Locate4
if %SkypeVar%==no goto Locate5
:Locate4
echo yes >> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate6
:Locate5
echo no >> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate6
:Locate6
if %SpotifyVar%==yes goto Locate7
if %SpotifyVar%==no goto Locate8
:Locate7
echo yes >> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate9
:Locate 8
echo no >> ConfigVarini.txt
goto locate9
:Locate9
if %SteamVar%==yes goto Locate10
if %Steamvar%==no goto Locate11
:Locate10
echo yes >> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate12
:Locate11
echo no >> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate12
:Locate12
if %ChromeVar%==yes goto Locate13
if %ChromeVar%==no goto Locate14
:Locate13
echo yes >> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate15
:Locate14
echo no >> ConfigVarini.txt
goto Locate15
:Locate15
if %ChromeProfile%==1 goto Locate16
if %ChromeProfile%==2 goto Locate17
if %ChromeProfile%==3 goto Locate18
:Locate16
echo 1 >> ConfigVarini.txt
goto End
:Locate17
echo 2 >> ConfigVarini.txt
goto End
:Locate18
echo 3 >> ConfigVarini.txt
goto End
:End
cls
echo Files Configured!
```